# How to modify my regex so that it doesn't match?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote this regex:

```
String regex = "^\\s+something\\s+(not\\s+)?else\\s+([-,\\s\\d]+)$";
```

and this code:

```
String line = "something else 1, 2-3";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line);
```

`m.matches()` will return `true`, which is what I want.

However, for the following piece of code, it also returns `true`, but I don't want it to match. How do I modify my regex so that it returns `false`?

```
String line = "something else 1 2 3";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line);
```

Thanks!

**Update:** I'm not doing any range checking. I just want to see if there are commas between spaces in a list. So `1, 3, 5-7` are valid, but `1, 2 5-7` and `1 2 3` are not.

Comment: Are you concerned about 6 being in the range 5-7 or the missing commas?  Regular expressions are a poor tool for checking to see if characters could be in a range but are not.  Consider "1, 3, 7, 5, 6"

Comment: I'm not doing any range checking. I just want the list to have commas if there are spaces in the list.

Comment: Then I believe my answer solves that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't exactly say what you were trying to do, but if I were to guess, something like:

```
((\d+|\d+-\d+),\s+)*(\d+|\d+-\d+)$
```

Substituted for the last bit would only allow comma separated numbers and number lists